# Find/replace strings in JSON using Regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

How can I replace multiple string contents to empty strings in a JSON file using find/replace in VS Code? I assume regex can help here but I'm not clear on how to use it in the find/replace dialog. I've checked other questions on SO and haven't found a suitable answer.

**Example**

```
{
   "value":"93827364"
},
{
   "value":"72653423"
},
{
   "value":"37369425"
},
{
   "value":"59026204"
}
```

**Search term**

```
Find:     ?
Replace:  "value":""
```

Comment: Down votes with no reason given, way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about the values, you can use the RegEx [`(?<="value":")[^"]+(?=")`](https://regex101.com/r/7J06ki/1)

- `(?<="value":")` is a positive lookbehind, it makes sure there is `"value":"` before your match
- `[^"]+` matches anything but a `"` 1 or more times
- `(?=")` is a positive lookahead, it makes sure there is `"` after your match

Replace with nothing. Don't forget to enable regular expressions on the search on VSC (Alt + R by default).

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/7J06ki/1)

```
Find:     (?<="value":")[^"]+(?=")
Replace:
```

---

If your VSC doesn't accept lookarounds, you can use [`"value":"[^"]+"`](https://regex101.com/r/7J06ki/2)

And replace with `"value":""`

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/7J06ki/2)

[image]

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you for your detailed explanation!